# How to find all directional derivative?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to solve this excercise: find **all** directional derivatives of the function $f(x,y)=2x+y-\pi^2$ at point $(0,0)$.

Now, I'm applying the definition so I calculate the limit($\alpha \ and \ \beta$ are the directions and $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$)
$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x_0+t\alpha , y_0+t\beta)-f(x_0,y_0)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{2t\alpha+t\beta-\pi^2+pi^2}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0} 2\alpha+\beta$
But now I don't know how to use this result to find **all** directional derivatives. Can someone explain me how can I proceed to find the result?

Comment: Do you have the gradient/dot product version of the directional derivative yet?

Comment: It seems to me that you already *have* computed the directional derivatives in all directions.  The directional derivative in the direction $(\alpha,\beta)$ is $2\alpha+\beta.$  What do you think is lacking?

Comment: @Randall No, I don't have it

Comment: @saulspatz is right anyway.  I think you've done it correctly.  You can drop the last limit and get $2\alpha +\beta$.

Comment: I guess the point is that your answer SHOULD depend on two parameters, since it takes two to indicate a direction in the plane.  Don't expect anything simpler.

Comment: @saulspatz I'm not sure if it's correct to leave 2α+β as answer because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are just parameter

Comment: Ok so I can simply drop the limit and then I get the answer?

Comment: Notice that you have computed the derivative of $f\circ \gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the straight path $t\mapsto t(\alpha,\beta)$. This is equal to the directional derivative of $f$ scaled by the length of $(\alpha,\beta)$. If you want it depending only on the direction, all you have to do is divide by that length to obtain $\frac{2\alpha+\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}$.

Comment: Well yes, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are parameters, and they should appear in your answer somewhere, just as $x$ is a parameter in $\frac{d\sin x}{dx}= \cos x.$  There are so many different notations for directional derivatives in use that I'm reluctant to show you how I would write it, because it's unlikely to be the same way used in your course.

Comment: @scentofthetrees Isn't the direction usually taken to be a unit vector?  That's what I was assuming, anyway.

Comment: @saulspatz That is why you need to divide by the length, since arbitrary $\alpha,\beta$ don't give length $1$ vectors $(\alpha,\beta)$. It depends on the definitions in the course if they want directional derivatives depending on arbitrary vectors, or on directional (length one) vectors.

Comment: @scentofthetrees No, what I meant was that I assumed that when the OP said the direction is $(\alpha,\beta)$ that implies $\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}=1.$  Isn't that the usual convention?  That's how I remember it, anyway.

Comment: In my course we also use that convention

Comment: So thank you all!

Comment: @saulspatz You assume whatever you want. What I said is how a complete answer should look like. $2\alpha+\beta$ is the derivative in the direction of an arbitrary vector (including the information of its length), while $\frac{2\alpha+\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}$ is the derivative in the direction of a unit vector.

Comment: @Holo You are wrong. That depends on the course.

Comment: OP, if you want to I suggest to try to find the connection between the partial derivatives and the directional derivative. I'm sure I'll get there soon but it is interesting to try and do it yourself(also, it can help get intuition)